# Appending suffix to an array list in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have an array list of hostnames that I need to do two things with. The first is to take the list of server names and make them lowercase. The second thing I need to do is append a domain suffix. I've gotten the array list created and made the list lowercase, but I'm having issues appending the domain suffix. Example of what I have:
HOST1
HOST2
HOST3

```
$Stringarray = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@(“HOST1" ,"HOST2" , "HOST3", "HOST4")
$Stringarray.tolower()
$Stringarray
```

I can create an arraylist and then use .tolower() to get it lowercase, but I need each of the items in the list to include a domain name as well. For Example:

```
host1.contoso.com 
host2.contoso.com
host3.contoso.com
host4.contoso.com
etc.
```

I think a foreach command would work, I'm just not sure how to pass the argument.

Comment: Hi, have you some code to share with us, to make your issue more clear

Comment: Can add to your question the code you currently have (the array creation and then `ToLower()`) ?

Comment: Added as you requested.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a specific need to use an [`ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-6.0), you can simply construct your [`Array`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=net-6.0) in one go using a loop of your choice, [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.2) in the example below.

You can use the [`+` arithmetic operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arithmetic_operators?view=powershell-7.2) to concatenate strings.

```
$domain = 'contoso.com'
$Stringarray = "HOST1" ,"HOST2" , "HOST3", "HOST4" | ForEach-Object {
    $_.ToLower() + ".$domain"
}

# $Stringarray is now the expected result:
#
# host1.contoso.com
# host2.contoso.com
# host3.contoso.com
# host4.contoso.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this :

```
$Stringarray = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@(“HOST1" ,"HOST2" , "HOST3", "HOST4")
$Stringarray | % { "$($_.tolower()).contoso.com"   }
```